# Why crash when try to render svg image inside button

Tags: reactjs

I've created a library with custom buttons. Button folder contains 24 svg files.

From project I pass a text, a function and icon, but when try to render the icon crash and show me next error:

> > index.js:1 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I dont know why dont render the images, please can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { ReactComponent as ArrowIcon } from './arrow_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ArrowRight } from './arrow_right_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ArrowIcon2 } from './arrow2_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as BellPlusIcon } from './bell_plus_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChartIcon } from './chart_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChartLineSolidIcon } from './chart_line_solid_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from './close_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CogIcon } from './cog_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as DeleteIcon } from './delete_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as DownloadIcon } from './download_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as EarsIcon } from './ears_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as EditIcon } from './edit_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ExportIcon } from './export_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as FilterIcon } from './filter_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LocationIcon } from './location_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoutIcon } from './logout_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MapIcon } from './map_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as PlusIcon } from './plus_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ServerIcon } from './server_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as TagIcon } from './tag_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as TiresiasIcon } from './tiresias_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as UsersCogIcon } from './users_cog_icon.svg';
import { ReactComponent as VGeneralIcon } from './vgeneral_icon.svg';


import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'react-spinkit/css/three-bounce.css';

import './go-button.scss';

class Button extends React.PureComponent {

    handleClick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.props.clickButton();
    }

    getIcon = (nameIcon) => {
        switch(nameIcon.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'arrow': return <ArrowIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'arrow_right': return <ArrowRight style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'arrow2': return <ArrowIcon2 style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'bell-plus': return <BellPlusIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'chart': return <ChartIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />
            case 'chart-line-solid': return <ChartLineSolidIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'close': return <CloseIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'cog': return <CogIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'delete': return <DeleteIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'download': return <DownloadIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'ears': return <EarsIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'edit': return <EditIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'export': return <ExportIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'filter': return <FilterIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />
            case 'location': return <LocationIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'logout': return <LogoutIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'map': return <MapIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'plus': return <PlusIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'server': return <ServerIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'tag': return <TagIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'tiresias': return <TiresiasIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'users-cog': return <UsersCogIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            case 'vgeneral': return <VGeneralIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <button
                disabled={this.props.disabled}
                type={this.props.type}
                className={`${this.props.className} go-button ${(this.props.active) ? '--active' : ''} 
                    --${this.props.theme} ${(this.props.outline) ? '--outline' : ''} 
                    --${this.props.size} ${(this.props.primary) ? '--primary' : ''} ${(this.props.circular) ? '--circular' : ''}`}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                style={this.props.style}
                id={this.props.id}
            >
                { this.props.icon && this.getIcon(this.props.icon) }

                {!this.props.circular &&
                    <span>{this.props.text}</span>
                }

                {this.props.loading &&
                    <div className="c-spinner-animation w-100">
                        <div className="bounce1" />
                        <div className="bounce2" />
                        <div className="bounce3" />
                    </div>
                }
            </button>
        );
    }
}

export default Button
```

Comment: The SVG's aren't imported correctly by transpiler. Do you have an SVG loader in your webpack config?

Comment: no, I doint have a svg loader.. how can do it??

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I add SVG as Components and works perfectly.

```
const ArrowIcon = props => {

    return (
     <svg className={className} style={style} ....></svg>
    )
}

export default ArrowIcon;
```

In Button component:

> > import ArrowIcon from './SVGComponents/arrow_icon';

And in switch:

```
 getIcon = (nameIcon) => {
        switch(nameIcon.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'arrow': return <ArrowIcon style={{ display: 'inline' }} className={"go-button__icon"} />;
            default:
                return null;
        }
 }
```